# User sign issue in lowest version(android 2.3.6)

Tags: java, android, security, oauth-2.0, token

I developed one Android app it's working fine in 4.2.2 but not in 2.3.6 and first of all I'm unable to login in to my app with 2.3.6.
I'm using Authentication with [Account-manager](https://github.com/frakbot/Android-AccountChooser) it returns access token length of 139 characters in case **4.2.2** like.

> ya29.1.AADtN_Xh_Wg1ffx5MSXzcT9Gk1dgKSLjUTAGc01dEabXyn68FxwNtwhRkn7z_E37wV7lKXCjnntvmn9magfgMKXStPVprpsqHsR80wXzlFyjtYOJ69YGuiT0nt5UM_A4EfQn
>   ya29.1.AADtN_Vy6CouCIAGsh9NLXaMQAF1zHq3qgB2dJ8Oyvr8UBowZzKxqnsQtCfvwWet9QpWo0sJxEPFK8tPbLwRcG1DNeX4So9drhZrSJI-7TkVycdkBYqueCwOneEB5hDBbsr7
>   ya29.1.AADtN_Vy6CouCIAGsh9NLXaMQAF1zHq3qgB2dJ8Oyvr8UBowZzKxqnsQtCfvwWet9QpWo0sJxEPFK8tPbLwRcG1DNeX4So9drhZrSJI-7TkVycdkBYqueCwOneEB5hDBbsr7

but when I was trying to login with **2.3.6** it returns access token length of 70 characters like.

> ya29.1.AADtN_X4TA2THN6JjAmx6iVfY5HEsGPpVwH6soLe8siIHxEDosgteVJ3P_6NtlQ
>   ya29.1.AADtN_X4TA2THN6JjAmx6iVfY5HEsGPpVwH6soLe8siIHxEDosgteVJ3P_6NtlQ
>   ya29.1.AADtN_X4TA2THN6JjAmx6iVfY5HEsGPpVwH6soLe8siIHxEDosgteVJ3P_6NtlQ
>   ya29.1.AADtN_X4TA2THN6JjAmx6iVfY5HEsGPpVwH6soLe8siIHxEDosgteVJ3P_6NtlQ

I'm validating that access token at server side .It working fine for 4.2.2 but 2.3.6 it throws a below exception as

> WARNING: /user/signin: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseE
>   xception: 400 OK

please suggest me how to resolve this problem. It should be supported for above versions from 2.3.6.
Thanks in advance.